# Mounted samba share - how to check if it is online

Tags: linux, bash, mount, samba

I need to check if mounted is online in script.
and complete that check in maximum time of 1 second.

I tried:

1. `smbclient -L -U user%pass` - but it takes too much time, and makes a trash in destination serwer logfile because of relogin
2. `stat /mnt/samba/file` - but it stucks when the samba share is offline

Maybe one of You will help to find another way to complete that?

Destination samba is using SMB3.0 protocole.

Regards

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: You are not right. This is strictle on-topic. So how to develop software whitch is samba related?
I need to write a test in scripts.

Answer (score 0):

From programmatic viewpoint it's harder than it seems. 
To check for sure I'd say you have to create a file there or try to read a directory.
However linux doesn't support asynchronous [open system call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780822/linux-kernel-aio-open-system-call) 
And the same is the reason why utilities are hung for a long timeout (which should be about 2 minutes I guess, it's TCP-death minimum timeout)
So if you are going to implement this you should impose some smaller timeout, trying to make stat or open call on a destination folder and just terminate the thread (or send a signal there) when the timeout is expired.

Comment: I might be really off here as I've never used samba before, but couldn't OP use `timeout` of a number that's just slightly higher than a successful read attempt on the command reading a file? E.g. if it shouldn't take more than 1 second to read a file off it, OP could use `timeout 2` or something like that, and then check the output of the command. (To be clear: I'm talking about the UNIX tool [timeout](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html).)

Comment: @confetti stat is a syscall and you can't interrupt kernel processes what are waiting for IO. That is the root of the problem. May the user space return but then you have a zombie kernel process.